# android studio times out installing the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a question about running an app through the emulator on android studio.

My emulator device is able to turn on, but when running the app, install never completes so the app times out. I have tried invalidating cache and restarting, and I have installed the sdk platforms that are the same as the emulators and project, but these changes did not work. My computer cannot install emulator hypervisor driver for AMD processors or intel x86 Emulator accelerator, but I don't think it is necessary for the app to run since my emulator can turn on, right? also, any app has never successfully run on android studio.

The is no code other than the hello world that comes up automatically. This is an empty project with a minimum sdk of api: android 4.1. The device I am using is a pixel 2 with an api of 22. (size on disk 3.5 GB) for tools, I have android SDK build-tools 33, android emulator (31.3.10), and android sdk platform- tools (33.0.3) installed.
I have tried every forum that has the same issue as me but if you think there is one that can help me, please share it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulators aren't always the best so expect random failures. This is what I would try:

1. Make sure the app compiles properly (make sure you see BUILD SUCCESSFUL in your bottom "Build" Tab in Android Studio)
2. Make sure you have updated Android Studio and Android Emulator, Android Build Tools, SDKs etc.
3. Create and use a device with a higher API version. Ideally one with Play Store.
4. Depending on your development machine you might want to try a different architecture (ABI). Try x86 or x86_64 instead of what you've already tried.
5. In rare cases your existing emulator images get corrupted. Uninstall them in your SDK manager (Show Package Details) and install them again.
6. If possible try running the app on a real device (follow online instructions to enable USB debugging etc.) to verify the emulator is the problem.

Comment: I have tried these steps but any higher API terminates the emulator before it runs. I have also tried uninstalling and installing but it does not fix the problem. Thanks for the response anyways.